# How to deal with User input errors in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, if-statement, input, error-handling

so basically I am trying to figure out how to make an error return if the user inputs the incorrect string type. For example, if someone were to type "y" instead of the six button on the keyboard, because they were typing their score to get the grade in the program, what would I do? I tried using an else statement to say that there was an error, but PyCharm gives me the green checkmark and then my program errors out saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last): line 3, in 
> if int(score) >= 90: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'H'

this is confusing to me as I would think that the code would be read by the interpreter as checking if the input was an integer and then moving on through all the elifs i typed, then into the else statement, but I am wrong. What would be a better way to do this? Here is my code I wrote.

```
score = input("type your score on the exam as an integer to receive your letter grade\n")

if int(score) >= 90:
    print("A")
elif int(score) >= 80:
    print("B")
elif int(score) >= 70:
    print("C")
elif int(score) >= 60:
    print("D")
elif int(score) < 60:
    print("F")
else:
    input("ERROR: type your score on the exam as an integer to receive your letter grade\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would wrap your "user menu" with a *while*, like this:

```
while True:
    score = input("type your score on the exam as an integer to receive your letter grade\n")
    try:
        score = int(score)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int!")
        continue

    if score >= 90:
        print("A")
    elif score >= 80:
        print("B")
    elif score >= 70:
        print("C")
    elif score >= 60:
        print("D")
    elif score < 60:
        print("F")
    else:
        print("Please write a valid option")
```

You can also add an option for user to leave or just let them press CTRL + C to close the process.

Comment: I just read the python section on how try and except work and just wow, that is some good stuff. I didn't even know it existed, thanks so much man, this is really going to help me out now that I understand this!